# Selenium Chrome driver crashes on macOS

Tags: macos, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webrtc

I have automated tests for a WebRTC project. And chrome driver crashes on macOS when I try to use a microphone with allowed permissions to use it. Everything works on Linux, the problem exists only with macOS.

```
    val options = ChromeOptions()
    val prefs = HashMap<String, Any>()
    prefs["intl.accept_languages"] = "de"
    prefs["profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic"] = 1
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs)
    val driver = ChromeDriver(options)
```

Logs of the chrome driver:

```
[1111/144648.290128:WARNING:process_memory_mac.cc(93)] mach_vm_read(0x7ffee3670000, 0x2000): (os/kern) invalid address (1)
[1111/144648.443304:WARNING:system_snapshot_mac.cc(42)] sysctlbyname kern.nx: No such file or directory (2)
[1111/144648.462626:WARNING:crash_report_exception_handler.cc(239)] UniversalExceptionRaise: (os/kern) failure (5)
[1573480008.479][SEVERE]: Unable to receive message from renderer
[1573480008.479][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1573480008.479][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: disconnected: not connected to DevTools
[1573480008.479][DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Request: http://localhost:63323/json
[1573480008.480][DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Request failed
```

Does someone have an idea what could cause the crash? Any settings, like memory, etc.? Or this is just a bug in selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of experiments, I was able to fix this issue. But I still could not explain why this happens only on macOS. It seems to be the root cause lays in experimental options. Maybe it is called experimental for a good reason =) Instead of using `prefs["profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic"] = 1` to allow using microphone, I found that following option could be used: `options.addArguments("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")` Which works both Linux and macOS. Full settings for the chrome driver as follows:

```
val options = ChromeOptions()
val prefs = HashMap<String, Any>()
prefs["intl.accept_languages"] = "de"
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs)
options.addArguments("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")
val driver = ChromeDriver(options)
```

And additionally for Firefox:

```
val profile = FirefoxProfile()
profile.setPreference("intl.accept_languages", "de")

val options = FirefoxOptions()
options.profile = profile
options.addPreference("media.navigator.streams.fake", true)
return BrowserProfile.initDriver(FirefoxDriver(options))
```